# jQuery CSS .hide not complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Dialog box that is in the bottom right, I am trying to use simple jQuery hide/show to minimize it. It works for the most part, but .x_container is not completely hiding. There is a 1px white line that is still there. What is wrong with my code?

```js
function toggle_close() {
    $("#x_header").hide();
    $("#x_mainbody").hide();
    $("#x_footer").hide();
    $("#x_close").hide();
    $("#x_open").show();       
}
function toggle_open() {
    $("#x_header").show();
    $("#x_mainbody").show();
    $("#x_footer").show();
    $("#x_close").show();
    $("#x_open").hide();       
}
```

```css
.x_screen {
        position: relative;
    }
    .x_container {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 20%;
        width: 250px;
        max-height: 600px;
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .x_header {
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
        width: 210px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_close {
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_mainbody {
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 240px;
        min-height: 400px;
        max-height: 560px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_footer {
        height: 20px;
        width: 240px;
        background-color: whiteSmoke;
        border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_screen2 {
        position: relative;
    }
    .x_container2 {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 20%;
        width: 20px;        
    }
    .x_open {
        float: right; 
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: whiteSmoke;
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x_screen">
    <div class="x_container">
        <div><div id="x_header" class="x_header">Header</div><div id="x_close" onclick="toggle_close()" class="x_close">[x]</div></div>
        <div id="x_mainbody" class="x_mainbody">
            <p>Body</p>
        </div>
        <div id="x_footer" class="x_footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="x_screen2">
    <div class="x_container2">
        <div id="x_open" onclick="toggle_open()" class="x_open" style="display:none;">[*]</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not pertinent to your problem but the following line has an extraneous `<div>` pair that you can get rid of.
`<div><div id="x_header" class="x_header">Header</div><div id="x_close" onclick="toggle_close()" class="x_close">[x]</div></div>`

Comment: Just hide the **.x_screen** and everything inside it will be hidden as well.

Comment: @Difster, removed. thanks

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac, oddly that did not work. hiding it and .x_container were the first things i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem.. is you haven't hidden .x_container class yet.

and you don't need to hide all elements inside of container if your intention is only to minimize. It's working only with hiding x_container.

```js
    function toggle_close() {
        // $("#x_header").hide();
        // $("#x_mainbody").hide();
        // $("#x_footer").hide();
        // $("#x_close").hide();
        $(".x_container").hide();
        $("#x_open").show();        
    }
    function toggle_open() {
        $(".x_container").show();
        // $("#x_header").show();
        // $("#x_mainbody").show();
        // $("#x_footer").show();
        // $("#x_close").show();
        $("#x_open").hide();        
    }
```

```css
    .x_screen {
        position: relative;
    }
    .x_container {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 20%;
        width: 250px;
        max-height: 600px;
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .x_header {
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
        width: 210px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_close {
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_mainbody {
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 240px;
        min-height: 400px;
        max-height: 560px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_footer {
        height: 20px;
        width: 240px;
        background-color: whiteSmoke;
        border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    .x_screen2 {
        position: relative;
    }
    .x_container2 {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 20%;
        width: 20px;        
    }
    .x_open {
        float: right; 
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: whiteSmoke;
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x_screen">
    <div class="x_container">
        <div><div id="x_header" class="x_header">Header</div><div id="x_close" onclick="toggle_close()" class="x_close">[x]</div></div>
        <div id="x_mainbody" class="x_mainbody">
            <p>Body</p>
        </div>
        <div id="x_footer" class="x_footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="x_screen2">
    <div class="x_container2">
        <div id="x_open" onclick="toggle_open()" class="x_open" style="display:none;">[*]</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks, but that doesn't work. i tried that. that's why hid everything manually. i even hid .x_container.

Comment: hi @Seongjune Kim, your code is work. i used a #x_container instead of .x_container. thank you.

Comment: @7huan I'm glad to hear you made it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the `x_container` instead of the `x_header`, or give a name to the parent div of `x_header` and hide that as well.

That seems to be the only thing that's not being hidden in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a border on those elements which won't be hidden.
Try the following

```
.x_container{
border-left: 0px solid #fff;
border-top: 0px solid #fff;
border-right: 0px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show and hide `.x_container` directly.

```js
    function toggle_close() {
        $('.x_container').hide()
        $("#x_close").hide();
        $("#x_open").show();        
    }
    function toggle_open() {
        $('.x_container').show()
        $("#x_close").show();
        $("#x_open").hide();        
    }
```

```css
    .x_screen {
        position: relative;
    }
    .x_container {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 20%;
        width: 250px;
        max-height: 600px;
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .x_header {
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
        width: 210px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_close {
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_mainbody {
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 240px;
        min-height: 400px;
        max-height: 560px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_footer {
        height: 20px;
        width: 240px;
        background-color: whiteSmoke;
        border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .x_screen2 {
        position: relative;
    }
    .x_container2 {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 20%;
        width: 20px;        
    }
    .x_open {
        float: right; 
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: whiteSmoke;
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x_screen">
    <div class="x_container">
        <div><div id="x_header" class="x_header">Header</div><div id="x_close" onclick="toggle_close()" class="x_close">[x]</div></div>
        <div id="x_mainbody" class="x_mainbody">
            <p>Body</p>
        </div>
        <div id="x_footer" class="x_footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="x_screen2">
    <div class="x_container2">
        <div id="x_open" onclick="toggle_open()" class="x_open" style="display:none;">[*]</div>
    </div>
</div>
```